# Python Index error in a while loop for a simple weather information operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, index-error

Can anyone spot anything obvious with the below index error i'm getting? I've created a simple operation which takes data from a .txt file and prints the information in a specific format. It's not complex but i'm getting an index error and i'm not sure why as the index exists;

```
city_info = open("mean_temp.txt", "a+")

city_info.write("Rio de Janeiro,Brazil,30.0,18.0\n")

city_info.seek(0,0)
headings = city_info.readline().split(",")
print("heading index 0:", headings[0],"\n","heading index 1:", 
headings[1],"\n","heading index 2:", headings[2],"\n","heading index 3:", 
headings[3])

while city_info:
    city_temp = city_info.readline().split(",")
    print(headings[0], "of", city_temp[0], "is", city_temp[2], "Celcius")

city_info.close()
```

My index values are as below;

1. heading index 0: city
2. heading index 1: country
3. heading index 2: month ave: highest high
4. heading index 3: month ave: lowest low

This is my current output (which looks correct (ignore the numbers) but i just need to get rid of the index error.

1. city of Beijing is 30.9 Celcius
2. city of Cairo is 34.7 Celcius
3. city of London is 23.5 Celcius
4. city of Nairobi is 26.3 Celcius
5. city of New York City is 28.9 Celcius
6. city of Sydney is 26.5 Celcius
7. city of Tokyo is 30.8 Celcius
8. city of Rio de Janeiro is 30.0 Celcius

> This is my error: IndexError
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-5-fb9cc0942cef> in <module>()
>      20 while city_info:
>      21     city_temp = city_info.readline().split(",")
> ---> 22     print(headings[0], "of", city_temp[0], "is", city_temp[2], "Celcius")
>      23 
>      24 
> IndexError: list index out of range
> ```
>
> If i run the URL for the location the .txt file is stored in i get and i can't find any blank lines:
>
> ```
> <p> city,country,month ave: highest high,month ave: lowest low
> <p>Beijing,China,30.9,-8.4
> <p>Cairo,Egypt,34.7,1.2
> <p>London,UK,23.5,2.1
> <p>Nairobi,Kenya,26.3,10.5
> <p>New York City,USA,28.9,-2.8
> <p>Sydney,Australia,26.5,8.7
> <p>Tokyo,Japan,30.8,0.9
> <p> 
> <p>
> ```

Comment: Try catching the error in a try-except block and printing the values of `headings` and `city_temp` when the exception is raised.

Comment: Are there any blank lines in the file?

Comment: Check the line in your file after `Rio de Janeiro`. Most probably there is some error with `city_temp[2]`. There might be either a blank line or some formatting issues so that you have only 2 elements and hence `[2]` gives you an IndexError

Comment: If i run the URL for the location the .txt file is stored in i get and i can't find any blank lines;<p>

city,country,month ave: highest high,month ave: lowest low<p>
Beijing,China,30.9,-8.4<p>
Cairo,Egypt,34.7,1.2<p>
London,UK,23.5,2.1<p>
Nairobi,Kenya,26.3,10.5<p>
New York City,USA,28.9,-2.8<p>
Sydney,Australia,26.5,8.7<p>
Tokyo,Japan,30.8,0.9<p>
<p>
I'm am just adding one additional line to this (Rio), then output all lines from a loop and then close. For some reason if i remove city_info[2] altogether it creates an infinity loop.

Comment: it does look like there is an erroneous line at the bottom of the file with one headings line and then an empty city_info list beneath it. Is there an easy way to do this or should i repopulate the original data using a 'w+' write and overwrite the original values?

Comment: The **last**, `.readline()` results in empty list. Therefore the following `city_temp[0]` fails. Add `if not len(city_temp): break` bevor `print(..)`

Answer (score 0):

Since the file opened successfully, `city_info` is going to be `true` forever. The loop as-is, will keep reading until beyond `EOF` hence the content of `city_temp` becomes an empty list.

I think the loop should be rewritten as:

```
for line in city_info:
    city_temp = line.split(",")
    print(headings[0], "of", city_temp[0], "is", city_temp[2], "Celcius")
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful. Although i thought that the 'While city_info:' statement is only two whilst there is data in the original text file and once it gets to an empty row it becomes false. Is this not the case?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case.